# How to Access GridViewDataColumn of DetailRow on server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspxgridview

I am using ASPxGridView and not able to access text box, which is present inside **DetailRow** (i.e. inside second grid view not in master grid view)

Can any one help me

**ASPX**

```
 <Templates>
   <DetailRow>
     <dx:ASPxGridView ID="dgCustomers" runat="server" KeyFieldName="CustomerCode"                  OnBeforePerformDataSelect="dgCustomers_BeforePerformDataSelect" OnDataBinding="dgCustomers_DataBinding" Width="100%" OnRowDeleting="dgCustomers_RowDeleting" OnRowInserting="dgCustomers_RowInserting"
         OnRowUpdating="dgCustomers_RowUpdating">
        <Columns>
          <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="CustomerCode" VisibleIndex="0">
            <EditItemTemplate>
              <asp:TextBox ID="txtCustCode" runat="server" Width="50px" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
          </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
          <dx:GridViewDataColumn>
            <EditItemTemplate>
               <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
          <dx:GridViewCommandColumn ShowNewButton="true" ShowEditButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true" VisibleIndex="4">
          </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
     </Columns>
```

**Code Behind**

I tried something like this:

```
 ASPxGridView detail = dgDepots.FindDetailRowTemplateControl(0, "dgCustomers") as ASPxGridView;
        if (detail != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < detail.VisibleRowCount; i++)
            {
                var item = detail.FindDetailRowTemplateControl(0, "txtCustCode");
                TextBox textbox = detail.FindRowCellTemplateControl(i, detail.Columns["CustomerCode"] as GridViewDataColumn, "txtCustCode") as TextBox;
                var anything = textbox.Text;
                if (CustomerCodeArray.Contains(anything))
                {
                   //Something
                }
            }
        }
```

But while debugging i can see **textbox** showing null

Where I am doing wrong Please help me

Comment: you try to access to textbox in button click event?

Comment: yes but I did it with help of hidden filed

Comment: I store text box value in hidden field and use on server side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well I do this.

First I have an extension method to access a control y cell template.

```
public static object GetDataItemControl(this ASPxGridView _grid, int _visibleIndex, string _fieldName, string _controlID)
{
    return _grid.FindRowCellTemplateControl(_visibleIndex, _grid.Columns[_fieldName] as GridViewDataColumn, _controlID);
}
```

next, you should use the property **NamingContainer** of button to access to gridview located in detail row, and with this and the function you can access to textbox located in  the template. For example:

I use devexpress bootstrap but its the same.

The view, you need put a column name for access it.

```
<dx:BootstrapGridView ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="DataSource" KeyFieldName="KeyField">
    <SettingsDataSecurity AllowEdit="True" /><SettingsBehavior AllowFocusedRow="true" />
    <Toolbars>
        <dx:BootstrapGridViewToolbar>
            <Items>
                <dx:BootstrapGridViewToolbarItem Command="Edit" />
                <dx:BootstrapGridViewToolbarItem Command="Refresh" />
            </Items>
        </dx:BootstrapGridViewToolbar>
    </Toolbars>
    <Columns>
        <dx:BootstrapGridViewDataColumn Name="CustomCode">
            <DataItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCustCode" runat="server" Width="50px" />
            </DataItemTemplate>
        </dx:BootstrapGridViewDataColumn>
        <dx:BootstrapGridViewDataColumn>
            <DataItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" />
            </DataItemTemplate>
        </dx:BootstrapGridViewDataColumn>
    </Columns>
</dx:BootstrapGridView>
```

The code behind, we access to gridview using the property NamingContainer, then we access to control in template with the extension method.

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button _button = sender as Button;

    BootstrapGridView _grid = _button.NamingContainer.NamingContainer.NamingContainer as BootstrapGridView;

    TextBox _textBox = _grid.GetDataItemControl(_grid.FocusedRowIndex, "CustomCode", "txtCustCode") as TextBox;

    String _text = _textBox.Text;
}
```

I use this code and it works for me, if u have a question make it in comments.